# How to get details about msbi and tibco?

Tags: msbi

I had completed MCA in 2013. I am not comfort with programming. so i want to learn other courses beside programming languages.
presently which courses have more job opportunities?
suggest me a course from following list:
MS-BI
TIBCO
SAP(If sap, then which module?)
or any else.

I am in big confusion. Please reply me..

Comment: stackoverflow isn't about a "career guidance" website. Please read [topics you can as here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with MSBI. 
Learning MSBI would include working on tools like SSIS SSRS and SSAS. 
You can start with SSIS which would just require knowledge of TSQL and possibly a little of C# if u want to do a custom task.